# If the Wronskian for a set of functions is also a function, how does it relate to linear independence?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, determinant, independence, wronskian

I have learnt that if the Wronskian is zero, then the set of functions are linearly dependent.

For example however, for the set of functinos $\{x,e^x,e^{2x}\}$:

This is the Wronskian for the set of functions (By definition)
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x &  e^{x}  & e^{2x} \\
    1 & e^x & 2e^{2x} \\
    0 & e^x & 4e^{2x} \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

By cofactor expansion of the bottom row, it is equal to $-e^x(2xe^{2x}-e^{2x})+4e^{2x}(xe^x-e^x)$
which equals $(2x-3)e^{3x}$.

and this 'new' function has a value of $x$ which makes it equal to zero.

Does this mean that the set of functions are linearly dependent?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems to me that the set is independent.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake somewhere. Those functions are independent. The Wronskian is the determinant of a particular matrix - if you show your derivation of it we may be able to help find where you've gone wrong.

Comment: I should add - either the Wronskian is zero everywhere or nowhere. It's not possible to have a situation like this.

Comment: If you find a point $t_0$, where the Wronskian does not vanish, then the functions are linearly independent. However, the Wronskian can vanish identically even if the functions are linearly independent!

Comment: Hello @dbx I made an edit and showed how I got the Wronskian for the set of functions. I've double checked with a calculator and it shows that it is correct. So it does seem that the Wronskian can have a singular zero. However what Somos said seems to answer my question. I understand now that a singular zero does not imply linear dependence, but rather it has to be identically zero. But I would like to thank you all for the help. Very insightful and helpful

Comment: You don't even have to use the  Wronskian to see the functions are linearly independent. Those aren't constants and you have to look at the vectors, not single points. It's like a translation of linearly independent functions s.t. some $x_0$ is the intersection point.  Btw, interesting nickname!